# app.js:1 �� SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
//app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port`)
})
```

```
//package.Json
{
  "name": "weatherproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

**getting error when trying to start the server**

PS Z:\Programming\Web_Development\Web_Development_Udemy\NodeJs\API\WeatherProject\WeatherProject> node app.js
Z:\Programming\Web_Development\Web_Development_Udemy\NodeJs\API\WeatherProject\WeatherProject\app.js:1
��/

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

/* please help me i'm a beginner trying to learn js but here i got stuck for days don't know why this is happening */

Comment: check if you don't have BOM at the beginning of the file and save it w/o

Comment: By any chance does your `package.json` has `"type": "module"` property? if yes then remove it.

Comment: Doesn't JS require a semicolon to end a line?

Comment: @n1md7 - It's clear from the error message that nodejs is treating this as a CommonJS module.  See `/cjs/loader` in the error message.  So, that won't be it.

Comment: The issue is most likely because this isn't a plain text file and there is some binary junk at the start of the file.  Load this file into a plain text editor, clean out any junk and resave it as a plain text file.

Comment: @Steve - Semi-colons are optional in most cases.  There are some cases where a lack of a semi-colon can cause a problem (which is why I always used them), but that is not an issue in this case.

Comment: Your file starts with two UTF-8 encoded Unicode Replacement Characters (0xEF 0xBF 0xBD), which means the original was likely encoded with a text encoding other than UTF-8 but the editor that the file was saved with tried to interpret it as UTF-8 nonetheless.